# Totally ramified $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field, that is, $K$ is of characteristic $0$ and the residue field is perfect of characteristic $p$. On
many places, it writes let $K_\infty$ be a
totally ramified $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $K$. But I don’t know how to show such extension exists. Can you help me?

Comment: For $p$ odd, the natural choice is $K(\zeta_{p^\infty})^H$ where $H$ is the subgroup of automorphisms of the form $\zeta_{p^n} \to \zeta_{p^n}^{\zeta_{p-1}^l\bmod p^n}$ (which  can be any subgroup of $\mu_p$, depending on $K$), the key idea being that $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q}_p) \cong \Bbb{Z}_p^\times= \mu_{p-1} \times (1+p\Bbb{Z}_p)\cong \mu_{p-1} \times \Bbb{Z}_p$. For $p=2$ it is $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}K( \zeta_{2^n}+\zeta_{2^n}^{-1})$

Comment: @reuns I can't fully understand what you say. I can see ${Gal}(K(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})/K)=G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$. I guess then you say $G=H \times p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $\mu_{p-1}$(or $\mu_p$?). But why can you say this?